# JQuery Slider Changes Image Before Fading Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my slideshow, the image is supposed to change after the image fades out, but the image instead changes before the image is changed. In other words the image changes, then fades out and fades back in. I placed the `fadeOut` method before the image source is changed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-section">
    <img src="img/seattleskyline.jpg" alt="Seattle Skyline" id="center-image" />
    <div class="caption">I still have absolutely no idea what this building is</div>
    <button id="sliderLeft"></button>
    <button id="sliderRight"></button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#center-image
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
}

.image-section
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.image-section .caption
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: #474747;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.image-section #sliderLeft
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border: 0;
}

.image-section #sliderRight
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var images = ["img/seattleskyline.jpg", "img/spaceneedle.jpg", "img/ferriswheel.jpg"]
var index = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sliderRight").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#sliderLeft").fadeIn(1000);

        function changeImage()
        {
            index++;
            if (index > images.length - 1)
            {
                index = 0;
            }
            var target = document.getElementById("center-image");
            $("#center-image").fadeOut(1000)
            target.src = images[index]; 
            $("#center-image").fadeIn();
        }

        setInterval(changeImage, 4000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, `fadeOut` takes 1000 milliseconds to complete. Javascript doesn't know this and doesn't care so it starts the fadeout then immediately changes the image (the next line of code). Fortunately, jQuery allows you to specify a callback method on `fadeOut`. Try this version of `changeImage()`:

```
function changeImage()
{
    index++;
    if (index > images.length - 1)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    var target = document.getElementById("center-image");
    $("#center-image").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        target.src = images[index]; 
        $("#center-image").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

This code is untested but it'll certainly get you on the right track. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `complete` callback parameter of the fadeOut function http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Like this:

```
$("#center-image").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        target.src = images[index];
        $("#center-image").fadeIn(); 
});
```